# running a time function in background?

Tags: c, time

Im developing a game on xcode in which the user puts some value of time between 5 and 15 seconds for each play. The game should run until the time reaches its end (value inserted by the user). I’ve not been able to code this, I’ve tried wait(), diff_time, sleep() but those didn’t work out since sleep() actually stops the processes entirely. What I’m trying to say is, is there a function of time that can run in “background” and when the time ends return some value that I can use for... let’s say an if statement, run the game until that value is returned. 
Thank you everyone.

Comment: You can try multithreading using `pthread.h`.

Comment: On what platform this game is supposed to run?

Comment: @Jabberwocky MAC OS X I’m programming on XCODE

Comment: @AntonioMartins you should mention this in the question. You can [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 3):

Begin by getting the current [time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) as a starting point. Then in your main event loop get the current time *right now*, and compare to the starting time. If the difference is equal or larger than the timeout (`5` to `15`) then "perform" your event.

This of course relies on the fact that almost *all* systems return the time as seconds (since an epoch).

Comment: Very few embedded systems support this though. To begin with, you'll need a RTC with continuous supply in hardware.

Comment: @Lundin apparently the OP wants this to run on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>
```

You have the `time()` function who gives you the time, since `00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970`.

This is a good alternative because its a clock in the background. Use the `time()` function once a the beginning of your program, and after it will be easy for you to base your code on it.

Don't try to re-invent the wheel.